# Output to Local Time - Convert MySQL to MySQLi Function

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone

The following converts MySQL stored date to UK time with daylight savings. I'm trying to get the MySQLi equivalent?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '".date('P')."';");
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example find on [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Google is your friend. ; )

For the date format, it's still PHP and MySQL, nothing to worry about `mysqli`

Hope it helps.